# Is there a way in VS Code to hide 'deprecated' Extensions from Marketplace search?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In the VSCode Extensions panel listings, is there a way to simply hide Extensions marked as `deprecated`?

For *most* folks, they generally won't have any use for these.

> Link to image: [Deprecated Extensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KKGT.png)

I've tried looking in the VS Code Settings for something similar, and couldn't find one.

Also looked at the `@deprecated` filter in the Extensions search box.
Of course that shows ***only*** deprecated items, but I don't know how to "Invert" this search criteria (*i.e. something like* "`NOT @deprecated`")

Comment: `@deprecated` also only filters whatever extensions you have installed, not the marketplace in whole.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of. I don't think it's possible at the time of this writing.

- What you're asking for is covered by this issue ticket: [Please add a category to filter "Deprecated" extensions on VSCcode #152757](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/152757), which got closed as a duplicate of [Provide a filter to list all deprecated extensions #151729](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/151729)- don't ask me why- that duplicate closure makes no sense to me and isn't very helpful, considering that from the rest of my research, inverting filters isn't supported- Ex. [please allow a filter on not installed extensions too #105564](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/105564).
- There is however this issue ticket in the backlog that you might be interested in: [Deprecated extensions should not be shown in search #149694](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/149694), which is at the time of this writing, [closed as out-of-scope](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/149694#issuecomment-1297170937). I suggest you give that issue ticket a thumbs up to show support for it, and subscribe to it to get notified about any future discussion and progress.